# I there a SQL join/ssub query that may handle this filtering requirement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have some experience with SQL but the following requirement has me stumpted after many hours trying to find a solution -

We have a MS SQL 2008 database for Students to register for various options other than class enrolments.

There are 3 x tables Students, StudentActivities and Activities
In a student's record they may register by ticking an Activity box (there are 15 possible Activities)

Selecting a Class generates entries in the StudentClass table - StudentID and the ClassID and the date in the Student record
The available Activities listed in the student record are derived from entries in the Activity table ActivityID and Description
I am trying to build the SQL commands to list Students who have unticked a particular Activity registration

I have built a temporary table of Student/Activity data by searching for Students with a regitration date and no Activity registration box ticked.
I cannot successfully work out the SQL filtering to end up with a set of StudentID's that have unticked the Activity registration box

My attempt has been to isolate the particular ClassID but I keep ending up with a couple of StudentID's that are registered for the Activity
Latest attempt follows - Tstudents is the temp table that contains students that have a registration date but no Activity registration entry

```
SELECT Tstudents.ID
FROM Tstudents
LEFT JOIN StudentActivity
ON Tstudents.ID = StudentActivity.StudentID
WHERE StudentActivity.ClassID !> 10
GROUP BY Tstudents.ID
```

10 is the Activity ID from the Activity table

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: @Trally . . . I added some line breaks.  But unless you are intending to emulate James Joyce, you can clarify the question by adding punctuation as well.

Comment: What does "unticked" mean? Is it a boolean value in a table, or it just reflects that the activity is not related to the student?

Comment: Unticked refers to the Student registration screen where they can select or unselect an activity.